# Probability generating function of the negative binomial distribution.

Tags: probability-distributions, binomial-coefficients

I am using the definition of the negative binomial distribution [from here](http://www.mathyma.com/mathsNotes/index.php?trg=S1C1_ProbNegBin). This is the same definition that [Matlab uses](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/stats/negative-binomial-distribution.html#brn2ivz-102). For convenience,

$$P(k) =  {r + k -1 \choose k}p^r(1-p)^k ,$$

where $p$ is the probability of success. $P(k)$ is the probability of $k$ failures before $r$ successes. The probability generating function is supposed to be,

$$ g(x) = \left(\frac{p}{1-(1-p)x}\right)^r.$$

However, I am trying to prove this. Steps:

$$g(x) = \sum^{\infty}_{k=0} P(k)\, x^k$$

$$= \sum^{\infty}_{k=0} {r + k -1 \choose k}p^r(1-p)^k \, x^k $$

$$ = p^r \sum^{\infty}_{k=0} {r + k -1 \choose k}(x(1-p))^k. $$

I suppose the next step would be to show that,

$$ \sum^{\infty}_{k=0} {r + k -1 \choose k}(x(1-p))^k = \frac{1}{(x(1-p))^r}.$$

Is there a formula (or theorem) for infinite sums involving binomial coefficients that I can apply to get this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually, what you want to show is

$$(1-y)^{-r} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{k+r-1}{k} y^k$$

You can see this using the generic rule:

$$(1-y)^{-r} = 1 + (-r) (-y) + \frac{1}{2!} (-r)(-r-1) (-y)^2 + \frac{1}{3!} (-r)(-r-1)(-r-2) (-y)^3+\ldots$$

This is really just a Maclurin expansion of $(1-y)^{-r}$.  Take a look at the coefficient of $y^k$:

$$\begin{align}\frac{1}{k!} (-1)^k (-r)(-r-1)\ldots(-r-k+1) &= \frac{(r+k-1)(r+k-2)\ldots(r+1)(r)}{k!}\\ \end{align}$$

Now compare that to

$$\binom{k+r-1}{k} = \frac{(k+r-1)!}{k! (r-1)!} = \frac{(r+k-1)(r+k-2)\ldots(r+1)(r)}{k!} $$

Set $y=x (1-p)$ and you are done.

Comment: Ah yes, I made a mistake typing that out. Will work it out later and accept your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
With
$\ds{\on{P}\pars{k} =
{r + k - 1 \choose k}p^{r}\,\pars{1 - p}^{k}}$:
\begin{align}
\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\on{g}\pars{x}} & \equiv
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\on{P}\pars{k}\,x^{k} =
p^{r}\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{r + k - 1 \choose k}
\bracks{\pars{1 - p}x}^{\,k}
\\[5mm] & =
p^{r}\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\braces{{\bracks{-r - k + 1} + k - 1 \choose k}\pars{-1}^{k}}
\bracks{\pars{1 - p}x}^{\,k}
\\[5mm] & =
p^{r}\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{-r \choose k}
\bracks{-\pars{1 - p}x}^{\,k} =
p^{r}\,\bracks{1 - \pars{1 - p}x}^{\,-r}
\\[5mm] & =
\bbx{\bracks{p \over 1 - \pars{1 - p}x}^{r}} \\ &
\end{align}